# What kind of RSA is this?

Tags: rsa

I'm currently trying to write a server emulator for a multiplayer game. I've found what I believe to be the RSA keys. I've found that by editing them I can get the real login server to reject them saying they are corrupt, IE. not encrypted properly. So from that I can confirm they are the correct keys. However, I can't figure out how to generate my own because they are a little weird.

The modulus is 511 bits long and the exponent is 128. 
Does this mean they are a 512-bit RSA key? When I generate my own, my public keys exponent is much smaller at only 17 bits long. How can I create my own key pair that is this strange size?

Sorry if this is a bad question, I am new to this.

Comment: What makes you think that they're RSA keys? What makes you think that the parts have these sizes? Such sizes would indeed be very strange. If you tell us *everything* you've found out about how these keys are represented and used, we may be able to help. As it is, I don't think it's possible to deduce any useful information from your question, other than “you're probably reading it wrong”.

Comment: In the code they are used like this:

BigInteger bigInteger3 = new BigInteger(arrby);

BigInteger bigInteger4 = bigInteger3.modPow(bigInteger, bigInteger2);

bigInteger and bigInteger2 are the exponent and modulus values.
bigInteger3 is the incoming buffer to decrypt

sorry for the variable names. They are decompiled

Comment: That's really a bad implementation.

Comment: Its not mine, its from a game from around 2005

Comment: @TylerH if you are user60258 you may want to [merge your accounts](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean they are a 512-bit RSA key?

No, this means they're using a 511-bit RSA key. A 511-bit key is for all security-related aspects essentially the same as a 512-bit key, but well, *technically* it isn't.

> When I generate my own, my public keys exponent is much smaller at
>   only 17 bits long.

The implementation you used to generate the keys probably picked the standard exponent which is $e=65537=2^{16}+1$, whereas the developers of the key in question probably rolled their own key generation and just generated a random 128-bit exponent, which is valid, albeit quite slow.

> How can I create my own key pair that is this strange size?

What they have likely done is they sampled two primes $p,q$ that satisfy $2^{255}\leq p,q<2^{256}$ and got two primes which are closer to $2^{255}$ than to $2^{256}$ which results in their product only taking up 511 instead of the expected 512 bits. One small scale example for this would be $17$ and $19$ which when multiplied yield $323$, the latter taking only 9 bits to represent and the former two both taking 5 bits each to represent.

What you can now do is to either just break the key-pair they used by factoring their modulus, which would [cost about 50-100USD on Amazon's AWS EC2 these days](https://github.com/eniac/faas), this may be illegal though. Or you could just instruct your implementation to generate 511 bit keys if you really want to, which *should* work, otherwise you'll probably have to generate your own primes and just try 256-bit primes until you get a pair that yields a 511-bit product and then do the RSA key generation math, it's no that hard and I *think* the Java standard library has helper functions for that. Using this way you can also just pick a 128-bit public key. But note that depending on how you implement the prime search the private key may be easily factorable, but then this may not matter to you.

Comment: If you generate a 512 bit key, you have an excellent chance the MSB will be 0 and that ia a 511 bit key.

Comment: @MeirMaor actually, most software packages have measures implemented to prevent this case from happening, eg by ensuring the most significant is larger than $\sqrt 2\cdot 2^7$ IIRC. That is if you request a 512-bit key from a good implementation you will actually get a 512-bit key and not a 511-bit one.

Comment: Obligatory reference: [Petr Švenda, Matúš Nemec, Peter Sekan, Rudolf Kvašňovský, David Formánek, David Komárek, and Vashek Matyáš, ‘The Million-Key Question—Investigating the Origins of RSA Public Keys’, in Proceedings of the 25th USENIX Security Symposium, USENIX Security 2016, pp. 893–910](https://www.usenix.org/node/197198).  It's a beautiful paper—everyone should read it!

Answer (score 0):

The key size of RSA is the size of the public modulus $N$. Thus it is likely 512-bit RSA if it is indeed an RSA key. As to the public exponent $e$, it is valid as long as it is co-prime to $\phi(N)=(p-1)(q-1)$, so that you can find $d$ that satisfies $e\cdot d \equiv 1 \bmod \phi(N)$. Usually for efficiency, a small exponent like 65537 is used, but you can generate a random longer one if there is a reason ro do so.

Comment: However, in this case, the keys length is 511

Comment: yes, 1 bit doesn't make too much difference, it is roughly 512-bit, which I guess is the goal of the game developer. You can call it RSA-511 if you want. It is likely they "homebrewed" their own implementation and did not quite work out how to generate proper keys.